# Tridiion UGC Implementation in MVC .NET website

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, odata, ugc

Using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 
I have a requirement from my client to submit and manage comments on a e-commerce website using UGC. Currently, I think, I have correctly installed and configured UGC on CME GUI, Moderation and Community Web service, Deployer and my website.
Both the Web services are working fine, running it in the browser.
I am able to save and delete a comment from CME GUI, unable to edit a comment (I think it is because a Hotfix requires from Tridion customer support).
I created a stand alone web page (.aspx) and manually added Default UGC Template code to submit comments. But, when i enter comments in the text area and clic submit, page gets reloaded and nothing happens. None of the end user comment is getting saved in Tridion_ugc DB or in the CME created page.

I am unable to find any logs (cd_core, application logs, event viewer)of the website.
Am I missing any configuration or the code related to the rendering or submitting of comments on my web page is incorrect ?

Can anyone provide some pointers on UGC Implementation using MVC .NET ?

I can provide further details of the configurations I have done.

Awaiting for your suggestions / answers. Kindly, help .

Comment: Check this link if it helps http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14042/error-in-ugc-implementation-in-dd4t-application     .  I have implemented it in my DD4T application using Tridion.ContentDelivery.UGC.dll